# Form with jQuery Validation: this.appendChild(a) error on IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, validation

Okay, final question about this form I hope. It's fully functional, except for one error on IE8 that doesn't seem to be documented anywhere (in this context, that I can find...).

If I run this form in IE9's IE8 mode, I see the following in the dev tools

`SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access. 
jquery.min.js, line 2 character 65772`

which corresponds to `this.appendChild(a)` in jquery.min.js

If I ignore the error, verification still works in IE8, however. No trouble at all in IE9, Chrome, Firefox.

Functional snippet of my verification code...

```
<head>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>


<style>

.incomplete {
    border: 1px solid red;
    }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //form validation start
   $(document).ready(function() {

   $("#form").validate({
        errorLabelContainer: "input",
        wrapper: ".form",
        keyup: false,
        onfocusout: false,
        onclick: false,
        onchange: false,
        errorElement: "input",
        errorClass: "incomplete",
        rules: {
            organization: {
                defaultInvalid: true,
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
                },
            firstname: {
                defaultInvalid: true,
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
                },
            lastname: {
                defaultInvalid: true,
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
                },
            email: {
                defaultInvalid: true,
                required: true,
                email: true
                },
            phone: {
                defaultInvalid: true,
                required: true,
                minlength: 10
                },
        }
    });
   }); 
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="border">
    <div id="form_title">REQUEST INFO</div>
    <form id="form" name="form_container" action="#">
        <!-- fields -->
        <input id="organization" type="text" name="organization" />
        <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" />
        <input id="lastname" type="text"  name="lastname" />
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" />
        <input id="phone" type="text" name="phone" />
        <!-- submit button -->
        <input id="button" name="submit" class="button" type="submit" value="submit" /> 
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I couldn't have gotten this working so far without you guys' help, so thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was never able to truly get to the bottom of this but I found something that works in IE8 w/o errors.

Main difference is that `errorLabelContainer` was changed to the form's class instead of the individual input and `errorElement` was removed (it was no longer needed I realized).

```
wrapper: ".formwrapper",
keyup: false,
onfocusout: false,
onclick: false,
onchange: false,
errorLabelContainer: ".form",
errorClass: "incomplete",
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but you have a small syntax error:

```
phone: {
            defaultInvalid: true,
            required: true,
            minlength: 10
            },
```

Note the extra comma. It is the last one in the list and doesn't need it. It is possible that `appendChild` is using a blank rule after this comma and that is the error?

Comment: @Sparky672 - lol, everything else seemed pretty legit so this was all I could think of.

Comment: I removed my comment since I'm now finding conflicting information on this for IE8.

Comment: Thanks for the note about the syntax. This IE8 issue still remains though :(